# String input not recognized in Python script run in Docker container

Tags: python, docker

New to Docker.  I have a basic Python project which reads a text file (docx, pdf or txt) and takes user input search terms (strings) to pull complete sentences containing the terms.  The script works as expected from both the terminal and the console (Windows).  I want to run the script on another computer that does not have Python, so I created a Docker image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
ADD eluciDoc.py .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./eluciDoc.py"]
```

I am able to run the script using the image from the terminal with the following:

```
docker run -i [image name]
```

and can input the file path (directly, cut/paste, drag/drop) as a string. The script is supposed to detect the file type and read it in.  However, it just returns the designed error message ("Invalid file type") and re-prompts an input, which makes me believe it is not reading the string.  As it runs directly through the terminal and console, I assume the problem is with how I am running the image.

I tried creating the image with CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT, but it did not change the result.  I also tried using the "-i -t" flags when using the image, and it returned the following after inputting the file: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:[input file path].  Thanks for viewing.

Comment: The Docker container runs in an isolated environment; it can't access files on the host.  You would need a `docker run -v` option to mount parts of the host filesystem into the container, and then also deal with some potentially thorny permission problems.  Rather than having your end users install Docker, learn a very long command line, and tackle the permission problem, just installing Python (presumably on a Windows host) might be easier.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct.  The project uses subprocess calls which makes it unwieldy to use docker.  Your suggestions seems to be the better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the files visible to the script inside the docker container? You can try to open shell to the container by running `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh $image_name` and try to find the files.

The docker container has its own filesystem and cannot see files that are on the filesystem of the host machine. To make the files available to the script running in the container you can either:

- copy them to the container with [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in Dockerfile or [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command, or
- [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) file or directory to the container.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  As I was exploring your solution I realized that because the script has subprocess calls to other apps, using docker to deploy it becomes too unwieldy, as David Maze suggests in his comment.  The better workable solution for me is to install Python on another computer.  Much appreciated though.